# Regex not matching words with dots

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression that will not match words, numbers and words with dots (like C.I.A)
So far I have(i'm coding with visual studio) :

```
` Regex reg_exp = new Regex([^a-zA-Z0-9ÀÁÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ])`
```

It allows me to not match words and numbers. But I didn't find the thing that also make this regular expression not match words with dots and match dots that are in the end of a sentence.

Comment: As dots are special characters in a regex you need to escape them in your regex. `\.` should do the trick

Comment: @Secespitus within `[..]` you do not have o escape `.` character. It will then match it as a dot character and not "any". [example](https://regex101.com/r/ctJz2w/1)

Comment: There are many letters (even whole alphabets) you don't have in the regex. Maybe it is not the problem in your case, but since you didn't provide in which language those words are I feel that it should be mentioned here.

Comment: @Artholl the words will be in french. I don't think that in french there are more letters than what i write in the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
Regex reg_exp = new Regex([^a-zA-Z0-9ÀÁÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ.]|\.\s)
```

I added the `.` to the set of characters not to match so it won't be matched, and added an alteration `|\.\s`, which matches all dots followed by any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks; represented by `\s`).

[Example on regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3g8ik)

Comment: Thank you it is exactly what i was looking for.